# How to set arrays of string to @EnableJpaRepositories from property files

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a jpa configuration file with `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotaion. I set this annotaion value from `application.properties` file like this :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("${jpa.repository.packages}")
public class JPAConfiguration {
    ....
}
```

and here is my application.properties file:

```
jpa.repository.packages=com.epms.model
```

and it works perfect. but i want to specify multiple packages for @EnableJpaRepositories . so i changed my config file to this :

```
jpa.repository.packages=com.epms.model,com.ecms.model
```

and also configuration file to this :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("#{'${jpa.repository.packages}'.split(',')}")
public class JPAConfiguration {
}
```

but it's not working . any idea ? how can i do this in my configuration file?

Comment: all the packages you want to scan are under the com package?

Comment: no and i have to load them from config file

Comment: @zhozhe I'm dealing with the exact same problem. I don't want to hardcode the repository packages but haven't found a way to do it. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: @zerayaqob as exoddus said in his answer it seems there is no way to do this in spring yet

Answer (score 6):

As @amicoderozer is asking, if your classes share a common base package you only must indicate that root package.

If it's not your case (despite you are loading from a config file or you are declaring them manually) maybe the problem (*will help posting any Exception or Runtime trace*) is the way the `split` method is used. It returns an array, and I guess the generated code will be like this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("jpa.repository.packages1","jpa.repository.packages2")
```

That code doesn't compile.

<s>Never tried Spring EL inside the annotation of a component, but despite this, maybe you should indicate the [basePackages](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#basePackages--) this way:</s>

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "#{'${jpa.repository.packages}'.split(',')}")
```

If doesn't work, I recomend you first test it by manual array declaration:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.epms.model","com.ecms.model" })
```

Be sure all works as you expect, and then try again reading and parsing from config file.

---

**UPDATE:**
 After some readings, I've concluded that is not possible do what you want. The `SpEL` is allowed [in many places](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) but for annotations there is only documentation and working examples with `@Value` annotation.

Comment: as i said to @amicoderozer in my case there is different packages and i have to use this approach. also i tried this by manual array declaration and it works perfect but when i want to use SPEL it fails.(even with your recommended way)

Comment: could you post what's the output when it fails?

Comment: it fails to load beans in that packages and spring throws this exception : No qualifying bean of type [ir.epms.model.user.UserRepository] found..

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.company.machine.repository", "com.company.system.repository"})
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.company.system.repository", "com.company.machine.repository"})
```